# Classic ASP and Signature Pad ADODB.Stream error '800a0bb9'

Tags: asp-classic

Using code for saving signature to file from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646982/classic-asp-and-signature-pad)

get error on line

```
bStream.Write( nodeB64.NodeTypedValue )
```

> ADODB.Stream error '800a0bb9'
>
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Using local server win 7 ultimate and classic asp.
Tried many different solutions but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it. forgot to add the right jquery js and css  head of my page.

Comment: I am getting the same error - but i have the jquery JS linked up - can you tell me what the issue was exactly?  Thanks

Comment: base64String = strFileNameData  'must be data field. That was my error...

Comment: thanks, can you explain more? i dont even see that link in the code

Comment: strFileNameData contains element data. Like  <div id="strFileNameData">your html here...</div>