# Saving PNG on server side with ASP Vbscript, from base64 data

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, base64

I am using Signature_pad to try save signatures on a site - in PNG format.

I'm trying to get a Classic ASP version of this app to save images to my server: https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

On client side - all works well.
Once I have the base64 code of the `canvas` in a field (via use of an existing method from the library) - I need to save that on the server-side and am running into an issue, receiving the following error:

```
ADODB.Stream error '800a0bb9'
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="?" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


 <input type="hidden" name="hiddenSignature" id="hiddenSignature" value="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" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my server side code, trying to save as PNG:

```
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
    Dim CanvasStream
     Dim lngBytesCount
    lngBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes
    response.write "-" & lngBytesCount
    SaveToBase64(BytesToStr(((Request.Form("hiddenSignature")))))
End If

Function SaveToBase64 (base64String)
    Set Doc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
    Set nodeB64 = Doc.CreateElement("b64")
    nodeB64.DataType = "bin.base64"
    nodeB64.Text = Mid(base64String, InStr(base64String, ",") + 1)

    dim bStream
    set bStream = server.CreateObject("ADODB.stream")
    bStream.type =  1
    call bStream.Open()
    call bStream.Write( nodeB64.NodeTypedValue )
    call bStream.SaveToFile(  Server.Mappath("/uploads/signatures/test.png"), 2 )
    call bStream.close()
    set bStream = nothing
end function


Function BytesToStr(bytes)
    Dim Stream
    Set Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        Stream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        call Stream.Open
        Stream.Write bytes  // this line is where is get the error 
        Stream.Position = 0
        Stream.Type = 2 'adTypeText
        Stream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
        BytesToStr = Stream.ReadText
        call Stream.Close
    Set Stream = Nothing
End Function
```

The error I get is mostly on this line:

```
Stream.Write bytes
```

But in my testing, I have also seen it come in reference to this line:

```
call bStream.Write( nodeB64.NodeTypedValue )
```

I have also tried using this question as reference, as well as others here, but to no avail.
[Classic ASP and Signature Pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646982/classic-asp-and-signature-pad)

Comment: Rather than posting a duplicate answer, flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Good point @Lankymart